# Animating Scroll doesn't work for some reason

Tags: jquery

i am trying to animate the ***scrollLeft()*** onclick event however when I add ***animate*** it creates an error

**Jquery error**

```
  var mypos = $('.grid-overflow-wrapper').scrollLeft() + screenSize;
        $('.grid-overflow-wrapper').animate({
          scrollLeft(mypos)
        },500);
```

**No error but does nothing**

```
 var mypos = $('.grid-overflow-wrapper').scrollLeft() + screenSize;
            $('.grid-overflow-wrapper').animate(function() {
              scrollLeft(mypos)
            },500);
```

**Works without animation**

```
 var mypos = $('.grid-overflow-wrapper').scrollLeft() + screenSize;
            $('.grid-overflow-wrapper').scrollLeft(mypos);
```

**Screen size**

```
var screenSize = $(window).width();
```

Comment: Where is the `screenSize` comes from ? Are you able to add reproducible example.

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var mypos = $('.grid-overflow-wrapper').scrollLeft() + screenSize;

$('.grid-overflow-wrapper').animate({ scrollLeft: mypos },500);
```